# Replicate Google Now search animation

Tags: android, animation, google-now

In the google now app when the search button is pressed (or you say "okay, google") then a small card pops up with a fluctuating circle representing the volume of the audio it's receiving and a decoding-type animation as it translates from speech to text. Is there such a way to replicate the animation? I can't find any tutorials on how to achieve a similar effect.

Example:
[image]

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `animateLayoutChanges` being true on parent `View`, when you change the target `View` height, it will be animated. And to hide others `Views` use a alpha animation.

Comment: @ThatGuyThere Did you achieved this mic fluctuating animation? I wanna implement similar effect in one of my project.

Comment: @ThatGuyThere Did you implemented this mic animation? I want to implement the same in one of my project.